# Cannot suppress certain warning globally

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-analysis, suppression

I have VS2013 with Code Analysis turned on. I want to suppress one type of message globally, so I have following code in `GlobalSuppressions.cs`

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1707:IdentifiersShouldNotContainUnderscores", Scope = "namespace", Target = "MyProject.MyNamespace")]
```

But my function name contains underscore still got warned/errored by VS.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void Do_Something_Successfully_Test()
{
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Just turn off the rule for that project? You can do this by creating a custom Code Analysis Rule File

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380660.aspx

Comment: Hi Jesse, I know I can create a rule set just for the project. But I still try to understand why my suppression does not work.

Comment: Scope=namespace just works for the namespace identifier, not for class name nor function name.